# Input field to populate GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, formview

I have the following code which defined my input field and my button:

```
<p>
<asp:TextBox ID="input" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" Text="Button" />
</p>
<p>
<asp:GridView ID="searchDisplay" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="searchDisplay_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:GridView>
</p>
```

I added the a Click event to my Button once pressed it should invoke the following method:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String keyword = input.Text;            // Gets text inputed
   List<T> = service.getTitles(keyword);   // Two problems here
}
```

I have 2 problems i need to solve:

1) `List` should be defined as `List<Publication>` however type Publication is not part of this solution so i dont know how to correctly bind the data that WCF service returns to it. I tried E, T, and ? as parameters to List but all i get are errors.

Solved
*2) I have a WCF service runing in another VS2012 instance how and in the first one i have it refrenced with keyword `"service"` why can't i access it's methods. I have a method in my WCF service that returns `List<Publication>` i tried writing `List<?> data = service.getTitles(keyword);` however this gives an error that the following is a type not valid in current context*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String keyword = input.Text;            // Gets text inputed
   var v= service.getTitles(keyword);   
   grd.dataSource=v;
   grd.dataBind();
}
```